How to run tests on a .dll file using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 command?
I'm facing an annoying issue with running tests in my YAML pipeline. The setup is as follows:
I have an Azure Functions project, for example, Users, which also has an xUnit test project, :Users.Tests. In the CI stage, unit tests are run using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. After that, the projects are built and published as artifacts, archived as Users.zip and Users.Tests.zip, and stored in the drop and drop-tests folders.
This is how the CI stage pipeline looks like:
parameters:
- name: azureFunctions
  type: object
  default:
  - name: 'Users'
    projectName: 'Users'
- name: azureFunctionsTests
  type: object
  default:
  - name: 'Users-Tests'
    projectName: 'Users.Tests'

variables:
  solution: 'Microservices.sln'
  buildConfiguration: Release
  outputFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish'
  zipFileName: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/microservices.zip'
  applicationName: 'Microservices'

stages:
- stage: CI
  displayName: CI
  jobs:
    - job: BuildTestPublish
      displayName: Build, Test, and Publish
      steps:
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Run unit tests
          inputs:
            command: test
            projects: '**/*.Tests.csproj'
            publishTestResults: true
            arguments: >-
              -c $(buildConfiguration)
              --filter Category=UnitTest
              --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" 
              -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura
        
        - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
          displayName: Publish code coverage report
          inputs:
            codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
            summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
            
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: Publish Azure function projects
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $azureFunctions = ConvertFrom-Json '${{convertToJson(parameters.azureFunctions)}}'
              $azureFunctions.projectName | ForEach-Object {
                dotnet publish $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$_/$_.csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$_ -c $(buildConfiguration)
                Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$_/* -Force | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$_.zip
                Remove-Item -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$_ -Recurse -Force
              }
            pwsh: true
            
        - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          displayName: Publish artifacts
          artifact: drop
          condition: 
            and(
              succeeded(),
              not(canceled()),
              ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
            )
            
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: Publish Azure function test projects
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $azureFunctionsTests = ConvertFrom-Json '${{convertToJson(parameters.azureFunctionsTests)}}'
              $azureFunctionsTests.projectName | ForEach-Object {
                dotnet publish $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$_/$_.csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests/$_ -c $(buildConfiguration)
                Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests/$_/* -Force | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests/$_.zip
                Remove-Item -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests/$_ -Recurse -Force
              }
            pwsh: true
            
        - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests
          displayName: Publish artifacts
          artifact: drop-tests
          condition: 
            and(
              succeeded(),
              not(canceled()),
              ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
            )

Once the CI stage is complete, the CD stage begins. The idea is to download the archived function zip file and deploy it using the AzureFunctionApp@1 task. After the deployment is complete, I want to download the Users.Tests.zip file and run workflow tests, which make requests to the newly deployed Azure Functions.
This flow is almost completed and this is how the running workflow tests task looks like:
      - task: ExtractFiles@1
        displayName: 'Extract function test package'
        inputs:
          archiveFilePatterns: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.pipelineName}}/drop-tests/${{testsPackage}}.zip'
          destinationFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/workflow-tests'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Run workflow tests'
        env:
          ProjectId: $(WorkflowTestsProjectId)
          OrganizationId: $(WorkflowTestsOrganizationId)
          AccessKeyId: $(WorkflowTestsAccessKeyId)
          AccessKeySecret: $(WorkflowTestsAccessKeySecret)
        inputs:
          command: test
          projects: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.pipelineName}}/drop-tests/${{testsPackage}}.dll'
          publishTestResults: true
          arguments: >-
            -c Release
            --filter Category=WorkflowTest
            --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" 
            -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura

The files are extracted, but when its try to run the tests, the command line throws this exception:

Testhost process for source(s) '/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.dll' exited with error: Cannot use file stream for [/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.runtimeconfig.json]: Permission denied


Invalid runtimeconfig.json [/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.runtimeconfig.json] [/agent/_work/5/s/workflow-tests/Users.Tests.runtimeconfig.dev.json]

Also, I forgot to mention earlier, but I'm passing environment variables to the test projects, and I'm not entirely sure if these environment variables are being passed correctly, when targeting .dll.
Additionally, I tried using a script or another test command, but the result was the same.
